# Java Swing app - Arraylist with circleobjects, how to draw them in a Jpanel inside a jframe?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I'm making a simple app that allows you to show different circle objects browse through them with buttons.

[image]

The problem is i have no idea how to print out my circleobjects into the jPanel.
When you first run the program the first circleobject should appear in the jPanel. Here's my circleclass:

```
public class Circle {
private int height;
private int width;
private Color color;


public Circle (int height, int width, Color color){
this.height = height;
this.width = height;
this.color = color;
}
public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(Color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}
public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}
}
```

And here is the first part of the GUI code. I've made 5 circleobjects in an arraylist.

```
public class CircleGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame{

public ArrayList<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();

public CircleGUI(){
    initComponents();
    circles.add(new Circle(15, 15, Color.blue));
    circles.add(new Circle(20, 15, Color.black));
    circles.add(new Circle(30, 10, Color.green));
    circles.add(new Circle(20, 10, Color.orange));
    circles.add(new Circle(35, 35, Color.red));     
    }
```

Now, how do i make my first object appear in the jPanel which is marked on the screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of your JPanel.

Then you do the drawing on the Graphics object, based on the data your current Circle object contains.

Comment: Where in the code do i add the paintcomponent method?

Comment: Create a new class extending JPanel, override paintComponent there, and use an instance of this class instead of your JPanel.

Comment: i've created a new class called draw, exending jPanel, with @override, and then i have:

public void paintComponent(Graphics.g){
super.paintComponent(g);
}
}

Now, i've tried everything from jPanel.getGraphics to jPanel.paintComponent but i can't figure it out.

Comment: See an example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734500/custom-painting-of-jpanel

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It does exactly what you want (except it paint Rectangles).

It actually shows two approaches:

1. Painting objects from an ArrayList (which is what you want)
2. Painting objects onto a BufferedImage

The basic painting code in your case is:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //  Custom code to paint all the Rectangles from the List

    for (DrawingArea.ColoredRectangle cr : coloredRectangles)
    {
        g.setColor( cr.getForeground() );
        Rectangle r = cr.getRectangle();
        g.drawRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
    }
}
```

Of course you would paint ovals and use your Circle class

Comment: Should i do this in a new class? Also, drawingArea is that my jpanel and ColoredRectangle is the class?